# C++Builder 10 TGrid

Tags: c++builder

Помогите пожалуйста с функцией Grid1SetValue:

```
void __fastcall TForm4::Grid1SetValue(TObject *Sender, const int Col, const int Row,
          const TValue &Value)
{
    if (Grid1->Columns[Col] == Surname)
    {
         colData[Row] = ;
    }
}
```

colData это массив UnicodeString, не могу записать значение Value в строку. Value->ToString() не работает, выдает ошибку

> member reference type 'const System::Rtti::TValue' is not a pointer

, как нормально преобразовать TValue в UnicodeStrig.

> Value->AsType

тоже не работает. Буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все оказалось очень просто, именно в версии 10 функции `OnSetValue` значение `Value` стало константным, и поэтому теперь функция тоже немного изменилась.

```
const_cast<TValue*>(&Value)->ToString();
```

А добраться до ячейки можно `Form1->Grid1->Columns[Col]->Controls->Items[Row]` значение будет опять таки `TValue`